# Is Lightning App supported in IE?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am following the trailhead modules for developing lightning apps.

The lightning app preview works without any issue in Chrome Browser but in IE...it hangs and displays "Page cannot be displayed"

Is Lightning App not yet supported in IE browser ?

This is my code

```
helloworld.app

<aura:application >
    <h1>Hello Lightning app !</h1>
    <h1> This is a test </h1>
    <c:helloworld />
</aura:application>

helloworld.cmp
<aura:component >
    <h1>Hello Lightning Component!</h1>
</aura:component>
```

EDIT : I tested this in IE 11

Comment: You should be more specific, as there are many versions of Internet Explorer. "IE" does not just describe one browser but several.

Answer (score 2):

> We recommend using Internet Explorer 9, 10, or 11. Internet Explorer 7
>   and 8 may provide a degraded performance.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_browsers.htm

Answer (score 0):

IE11 and above are fully supported for standalone apps and Lightning Experience etc - what version is your Salesforce org on? Have you opened a case on this yet?

I have asked the Aura Framework team to look into this and there is an engineer assigned and working on it now. So far we have not been able to repro any issues in IE11 though. Are you seeing any js errors, networks errors, etc in IE Dev Tools?